# Multiply a column (from Binance API) in a DataFrame with a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I wrote this code in Jupyter Noteebok where I get live BTC prices from Binance API in a DataFrame and now I want to multiply a variable to the BTC price column to create a new one, named "value".

```
def prices(crypto,interval,start):
    BTC_Owned=float(0.004)
    df=client.get_historical_klines(crypto,interval,start)  #for Binance API 
    df=pd.DataFrame(df)     
    df=df.set_index(0)    #set time as index   
    df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='ms')    #conversion from unix time 
    df.index.names=['Time']
    df=df.iloc[:,:1]     
    df.columns=['BTC_Price']
    df['value']=BTC_Owned * df['BTC_Price']
    df=df.astype('float64')
    #return type(df['BTC_Price'])   #pandas.core.series.Series
    return df
```

The error message I get:

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.

I already tried other ways of multiplication and get the same error.

Please help.

Comment: what is the type of the BTC_Price? share some data as its in the DF.  here is a guidance https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks! I added one line.

Comment: which line? not following you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's probably happening:

```py
BTC_Owned=float(0.004)
import pandas as pd

print("\nTry with BTC_Price values of type float:")
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,3], 'BTC_Price':[100.0,200.0,300.0]})
df['value'] = BTC_Owned * df['BTC_Price']
print(df)

print("\nTry with BTC_Price values of type string converted to float:")
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,3], 'BTC_Price':['100.0','200.0','300.0']})
df['value'] = BTC_Owned * df['BTC_Price'].astype(float)
print(df)

print("\nTry with BTC_Price values of type string (unconverted):")
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,3], 'BTC_Price':['100.0','200.0','300.0']})
df['value'] = BTC_Owned * df['BTC_Price']
print(df)
```

The first one works.

The second one works (and probably shows how to fix your error using `astype(float)`).

The third one gives the error you're getting when it tries to multiply a string Series by a float.

Comment: Solved! The 2nd one is the aswer! Thank you Sir!

Comment: Do you need any additional help with this question?

Comment: I understand now. You explaned very well. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted. There is another question on another topic that I have, if you don't mind checking:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72439172/generating-repeatedly-updating-graph-funcanimation-matplotlib

Comment: Sure, check my answer there.